# Android: React Native Overlap TouchableOpacity and View behave differently when there is backgroundColor style

Tags: react-native

I created 2 Views that display overlaps to each others. The top and the bottom

[image: Overlap with no background]

When the bottom view background wasn't configured. It responded to the press event correctly. Let's say when I press on the overlap zone, it showed that the bottom one had been pressed

However, when I configured the bottom view backgroundColor. When I pressed on the overlap zone, on Android, it responded as I pressed on the top view which I think it's incorrect. (iOS it responded correctly that the bottom was pressed)

[image: Overlap with background]

## Steps To Reproduce

Provide a detailed list of steps that reproduce the issue.
Here is an example component

```js
const OverlapseTouchExample = ({backgroundColor}) => {
  const [pressedBox, setPressefBox] = React.useState('')
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{pressedBox} pressed</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.box, {backgroundColor: 'blue'}]} onPress={() => setPressefBox('top')} />
      <View style={backgroundColor ? { backgroundColor: 'orange' } : null}>
        <View style={{marginTop: -75}}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.boxBottom, backgroundColor ? { backgroundColor: 'green '} : null]} onPress={() => setPressefBox('bottom')} />
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  box: {
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
  boxBottom: {
    width: 120,
    height: 200,
    borderWidth: 1,
  }
})
```

The problem found when set the backgroundColor to true
`<OverlapseTouchExample backgroundColor={true} />`

You could see it in Snack https://snack.expo.io/@gie3d/9b6c32 (Android)

Comment: may be zIndex can help you

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, it doesn't... it's displayed correctly but the problem is on the touch event.